# How to disable correctly CSS3 transition property when needed

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm working on a CSS transition property, and I have a problem when my JavaScript updates the same CSS value.

I made a simple example to understand.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let container = document.getElementById("container")
  let hovercontainer = document.getElementById("hover-container")
  let square = document.getElementById("square")
  
  let mouseMove = function (e) {
    let el = e.currentTarget;
    let delta_x = parseFloat(e.offsetX / el.offsetWidth).toFixed(2)

    square.style = "transform: translateX(" + parseInt(delta_x * 400) + "px);"
  }
  let mouseLeave = function(e) {
    square.style = ""
  }
  
  hovercontainer.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)
 hovercontainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #wrapper { 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
#wrapper {
  background: #a4d24b;
  display: flex;
}
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
}
#hover-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #EEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}
#square {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #a4d24b;
  margin: auto 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 3s;
}
#container:hover #square {
  transform: translateX(400px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- background -->
  <div id="container"> <!-- white -->
    <div id="hover-container"> <!-- gray -->
      <div id="square"></div> <!-- square -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On this code, the `transform:translateX()` position of `#square` is updated from 0 to 400px based on the mouse position:

- **done with CSS**: When the mouse enter on the white box, the CSS `transform` property is updated from 0 (left) to 400 (right) and the transition is done on 3s.
- **done with JS**: When the mouse enter on the gray line, the `transform` property is updated directly on the tag to "follow the mouse".

**Problem:** When the mouse enter on the gray line, the cube come nicely (with transition) under the mouse. But when the mouse move (fast), the attribute change everytime and the square didn't move at all (caused by `transition` property)

**Other try** I also try by adding `transition: all 0s` with **Javascript** to "disable" temporary, but now the square teleport himself when the mouse enter on the gray line.

(same code with update)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let container = document.getElementById("container")
  let hovercontainer = document.getElementById("hover-container")
  let square = document.getElementById("square")
  
  let mouseMove = function (e) {
    let el = e.currentTarget;
    let delta_x = parseFloat(e.offsetX / el.offsetWidth).toFixed(2)

    square.style = "transform: translateX(" + parseInt(delta_x * 400) + "px); transition: all 0s;"
  }
  let mouseLeave = function(e) {
    square.style = ""
  }
  
  hovercontainer.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)
 hovercontainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #wrapper { 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
#wrapper {
  background: #a4d24b;
  display: flex;
}
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
}
#hover-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #EEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}
#square {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #a4d24b;
  margin: auto 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 3s;
}
#container:hover #square {
  transform: translateX(400px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- background -->
  <div id="container"> <!-- white -->
    <div id="hover-container"> <!-- gray -->
      <div id="square"></div> <!-- square -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I merge both solution to get a nice and smooth moving square ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's really complicated.  What I got out of that is that you want to be able to move the mouse around without noticeable change in speed and for it to reach the pointer at about the same time as if the mouse never moved.  For that you basically have to listen for the first time the mouse enters the target area and update the destination *and* the transition delay so that it doesn't reset at 3 seconds.  Here's a demo that kind of does what you're asking.  It uses javascript to determine what the delay time should be and updates it while updating the target X value.  I did have to disable easing on the transition however, for to not look so jerky.  Hopefully this helps you understand the problem a bit more and maybe it can be worked into a solution for your needs.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let container = document.getElementById("container")
  let hovercontainer = document.getElementById("hover-container")
  let square = document.getElementById("square")
  let ts = null
  
  let mouseMove = function (e) {
    let el = e.currentTarget;
    let delta_x = parseFloat(e.offsetX / el.offsetWidth).toFixed(2)
        
    if(!ts) ts = new Date().getTime() + 3000;
    let d = Math.max(0, ts - new Date().getTime()) / 1000 + 's';
    
    square.style.transitionDuration = d;
    square.style.transform = "translateX(" + parseInt(delta_x * 400) + "px)";
    
    if(d === '0s') ts = null;
  }
  let mouseLeave = function(e) {
    square.style.transition = null;
    square.style.transform = null;
    ts = null;
  }
  
  hovercontainer.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)
 hovercontainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #wrapper { 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
#wrapper {
  background: #a4d24b;
  display: flex;
}
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
}
#hover-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #EEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}
#square {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #a4d24b;
  margin: auto 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
#container:hover #square {
  transform: translateX(400px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- background -->
  <div id="container"> <!-- white -->
    <div id="hover-container"> <!-- gray -->
      <div id="square"></div> <!-- square -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```